# Is there any way to intercept I/O operations from a Windows application so I can grab the data in real time in a different application

Tags: winapi

We have a Windows application that interfaces with a sensor array. It reads out the array of 37 elements 10 times per second and appends the set of 35 32-bit integers and 2 16-bit integers to a csv file in the Documents folder on the C: drive

We have neither the application source nor access to the developer, who left the company a couple of years ago, nor specifications for the array to system protocols. We now want to perform real time analysis of the data, but all of the communications between the code and the array are effectively a black box.

I'm not a Windows system programmer, but a million years (in IT time) ago I was a designer for IBM OS/360 so I have a basic understanding of file system structures and it seems to me that it should be possible to somehow intercept file "open" and "write" calls to the OS and perform "near" real time analysis. Any good ideas how to do it? Preferably explained in terms that an 80 year old whio only dabbles in Python and C/C++ would comprehend? I've thought of a disassembler. or executing in a debugging environment that might be able to trap the I/O calls and pass control to an analysis routine, but I have no idea of what tools might be available these days in the Windows environment.

By the way, one other thing occurred to me - the app also outputs a plot of the data from each sensor - not sure if that's something we could get at .

Comment: Any reason to prefer hooking the logfile writes vs. the raw traffic on the wire? If the I/O goes through a standard port, there may be tools available to monitor/capture that.

Comment: It depends of the IO (usb, serial, etc.) but for this kind of forensics work, it's often easier to go on the wire directly with low-level tool for example this for usb: https://freeusbanalyzer.com/ , https://www.usblyzer.com/, etc. and probably couple it with disassemble too.

Comment: Thanks much - unfortunately we don't know anything about how the current code communicates with the sensor array. The array consists of 37 sensors spread over 8 mini-cards and connected to another card that is based on an Altera FPGA and pulls the data from the array and sends it to the host over a USB link. The engineer who developed the adapter card and the sensor cards also wrote the WIndows-side code so there is no documentation for anything. However the idea of using a tool to watch the USB data flow is a good one so I'll give it a try. Thanks for giving me a lead to the USB analyzer

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard/supported way to hook into file I/O operations.

For this specific problem, the ideal solution will likely to be to use [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-readdirectorychangesw) to watch the file for changes and read them out between updates; 100 ms should be more than enough time to pull out the data, unless it's a network drive or similar. This obviously won't work if the application is preventing you from reading the file between writes, though.

In an absolute worst case scenario, you *can* hook into the application's writes by injecting the process with a DLL that overwrites the first instructions of `WriteFile` (or whatever it's using to write) in kernel32.dll with a hook on load. You can read more about this process [here](https://blog.nettitude.com/uk/windows-inline-function-hooking).

Comment: The *"standard/supported way to hook into file I/O operations"* is a [file system filter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/about-file-system-filter-drivers).

Comment: Thanks much - all suggestions are appreciated.